# Multiple mongoose schemas in a file not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two schema in single schema.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  

var user = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  add: String,
  role: String
});

var Organization = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  add: String,
  name:String
});

module.exports = {
  user: user,
  Organization: Organization
};
```

accessing it like

```
var models = require("../models/schema");
models.user.findOne()
```

it says `findone is not a function`

whereas If I use a single class in a file it is working.

I have gone through this link and did export like above

[cant get data from database after multiple schema declared (mongoose + express + mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857203/cant-get-data-from-database-after-multiple-schema-declared-mongoose-express)

but not working

any idea?

Thanks

With the help of @anthony I figure out the issue

I need to do the below

```
module.exports = {
  user: mongoose.model('user', user),,
  Organization: mongoose.model('Organization', Organization)
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you exports more than one file than you will have to import with curly braces `{ schema1 }`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  

var user = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  add: String,
  role: String
});

var organization = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  add: String,
  name:String
});

const userSchema = mongoose.model('users', user),
const organizationSchema = mongoose.model('organizations', organization)

module.exports = { User: userSchema, Organization: organizationSchema }
```

and then import

```
var { User } = require("../models/schema");
var { Organization } = require("../models/schema");
User.findOne()
Organization.findOne()
```

Comment: I am not exporting more than one file, just schema like variable

Comment: Ok I have found the issue, but your answer anyhow helped me to figure out the issue

Comment: You're trying to query on a schema! You have to create a model. Queries are made on Model instance, not Schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at it in this abstract way:

A mongoose.Schema is basically just an object.

A mongoose.model is a class that you customize with your schema object.

In other words, mongoose.model has all the database functions attached to it, the schema by itself doesn't.